# Understanding my .htaccess file in order to rewrite X to X.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website of PHP files that I'm hosting on SiteGround.com and want the links to look like "example.com/about" instead of "example.com/about.php".  I also want my `index.php` to be loaded when I visit "example.com" instead of "example.com/index"

So I did some searching and this is what I want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But the webserver already has a default `.htaccess` file which has this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Okay...so I tried to piece together what it is doing.  Based on my understanding, it enables the RewriteEngine, then sets RewriteBase to be `/`.  It then sets a rule looking for `index.php` and if it finds it, it doesn't check any other rule.

Otherwise, it falls through and checks if a string is not a file and not a directory and contains a `.php` extension, it redirects the root to `index.php` and stops.

So, I tried adding my three lines to the end of block right before the closing `</IfModule>` tag and it didn't quite work.  Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**

I modified my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

</IfModule>
```

In my HTML, I have:

```
<a href="about" .... ></a> <!-- link to about.php -->
<a href="/" ....></a> <!-- link to index.php -->
```

Is that right?  It doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Is not part of the original `.htaccess` file. It can't be, it makes no sense where it is, perhaps you added it yourself while experimenting.

The `.htaccess` file you have there, other than that line, is a standard method of putting everything through `index.php`. Probably for WordPress. So you need to decide what you want to do. Do you want to put everything through `index.php`, or do you want to use separate `.php` files with the extension added on the server side? Or do you want to do both? (in which case a combined approach needs writing) Are you still using WordPress? Perhaps you can just remove those rules.

Let me know and I can update the answer if you need more info.

**Update**

Your rules can be modified to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,NE]
```

That should fix it, I think the `\.` on the `REQUEST_FILENAME` line was breaking it, the rest are improvements.

If that's not working then perhaps mod_rewrite isn't enabled, or `.htaccess` files are not enabled. You can test it by putting some garbage on a line and see if you get a 500 error.

If the root doesn't serve index.php then you just need to add a `DirectoryIndex`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use separate `.php` files with the extension added on the server side. I want the user to be able to visit a url like "www.example.com/about" and have the server return `about.php`.  With the exception of the root which I want to have the server return `index.php` but the user sees as "www.example.com"

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  Can you explain to me what your rules are doing and why mine was wrong?  I'd like to better learn this for the future.

Comment: The best thing I can suggest it to have a look at [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It has details for each directive and explains everything that is happening with each one (so look at [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)). If you want more also [check here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/).